# Efficient method to compute distance between coordinates stored in MySQL DB

Tags: php, mysql

I have a function that calculates the distance between two sets of coordinates and I have different user coordinates stored in a MySQL database. I'm using PHP to calculate the distance between given coordinates with all other existing coordinates in the database.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `visible` = 'yes' AND `location` != ''";    
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if ($row["username"] !== $username) {
      $loc = $row["location"];
      $loc = explode(",", $loc);
      $lat2 = $loc[0];
      $long2 = $loc[1];
      $dis = distance($lat, $long, $lat2, $long2, "M");

      if ($dis <= $distance) {
      echo $row["username"] . "|" . $row["image"] . "|" . $row["info"] . "<BR>";
      }
    }
  }
```

This works fine with just a few entries in the database. But if there were, say, 20000 different locations (rows) in the database, then I assume it would take a considerable amount of time to check the distance betweeen the given coordinates and the others in the database.

How can I maintain efficiency with large databases and optimize the SQL statement?

The distance formula:

```
function distance($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2, $unit) {

  $theta = $lon1 - $lon2;
  $dist = sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($lat2)) +  cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * cos(deg2rad($theta));
  $dist = acos($dist);
  $dist = rad2deg($dist);
  $miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;
  $unit = strtoupper($unit);

  if ($unit == "K") {
    return ($miles * 1.609344);
  } else if ($unit == "N") {
      return ($miles * 0.8684);
    } else {
        return $miles;
      }
}
```

Comment: You can add the `username` condition in the SQL query using `where` clause, to reduce the number of returned rows and thus the iterations for `where` clause.

Comment: Check this for possible mysql solution http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/31629

Comment: You should restructure your table so the lat and long are their own columns. Take a look at the table structure here, https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3. Also while on that page look at the query further down for distance, using Haversine formula.

Comment: Please separate the fetching of the rows versus the `distance()` calls.  Then time each one.  This will determine whether mysql is to 'blame', or the distance function.  Keep in mind that 20K rows fetched and 20K complex function calls are each going to take some time.  But let's focus on the appropriate villain.

Comment: Please describe the bigger picture -- There may be a way to eliminate this entire set of 20K fetches and computations!  Or at least shrink it down to, say, only 20.

Comment: If coordinates are in separate columns then it should be easy to compute bounding box for given max distance and use "where lat between ... and long between ..." to use index and return only relevant set of rows for detailed examination.

Comment: The distance formula I am using is now on the first thread:

Comment: adding the username condition in the SQL query will only eliminate one result.  so i dont see the point in making the query longer for this reason.  Correct me if wrong